# Setting a custom navigation item backBarButtonItem icon [Objective-c]

Tags: ios, objective-c, back-button

I'm trying to set a custom navigation item backBarButtonItem icon.
So far I'm using this code on the preveous view controller's view did load:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];


UIBarButtonItem *myBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-arrow"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil
                                                                action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = myBackButton;}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

I have two icons and I can't figure out what is going on. I want to get rid of the native one and keep mine.

Can someone help me?

UPDATE:

Using:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-arrow"]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-arrow"]];
```

The result is:

[image]

It solves the initial problem, but I got a icon that is too big. How can I resize it? I'm using an icon that is 53x46px.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your-image"]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your-image"]];
```

Comment: I just updated the question with what you suggested me. Have a look.

Comment: It's because your image size is need's to be 22x22 for non-retina screens and 44x44 for retina. Create 3 images named somename@1 which size is 22x22, somename@2 44x44 and somename@3 66x66. And then do  `imageNamed:@"somename"` (without @1/2/3).